# Post data and file using Guzzle - PHP & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using guzzle 6.3 to post a file along with some data to my api built on laravel 5.5. When i post the data, i am not able to get the data sent to the api except the file posted.

**Client Side**

```
$client = new Client([
            'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]
        ]);

        $response = $client->request('POST',$url, [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'body',
                    'contents' => json_encode(['documentation' => 'First Doc', 'recipient' => ['78011951231']]),
                    'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen('/path/public/media/aaaah.wav', 'r'),
                    'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'audio/wav']
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        echo($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

**API Controller**

```
 if (($Key)) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'documenation' => $request->get('documentation'),
            'recipient' => $request->get('recipient'),
            'file' =>$request->get('file'),
            'media'=>$request->hasFile('file')
        ]);
    }
```

**Response**

```
{"status":"error","documentation":null,,"recipient":null,"file":null,"media":true}
```

Why am i getting **NULL** returned for the data that i am posting? Could it be because of the file that i am posting ?

Comment: We need to see your whole code for handling this call inside Controller

Comment: @NikolaGavric, i am sure it has got to do with the file i am submitting with multipart. Because when i send data without file, i am able to receive the data. The rest of my code works fine

Comment: The reason you are getting error response is because the `if` statement is false, meaning that `$Key` did not pass, now, to be sure whats the issue exactly, we need to see the rest of your code

Comment: @NikolaGavric, that is not the issue. As i said earlier, when i post without the file, i get all the data even with the same code above. I only get this error when i include the file. Thank you for your help

Comment: @CodeNewbie you can't know that it isn't the issue. It might as well be the truck currently standing in front of my office that is causing this. We need to see the entire block of responsible code to be sure where the fault is located.